# How to change currency format in plotly express hover data?

Tags: python, plotly-express

I have been trying to change the currency format in this plotly express figure in the hover data, without any success. I am looking to change it from US dollars to my home currency, GBP. Does anyone know what i need to do to achieve this? The documentation doesn't really go into it much.

```
fig = px.bar(
df, 
x=df['cat_level2'], 
y=df['count'], 
labels={"cat_level2": "Category", "count": "Product Count", "max":"Maximum Price", "mean":"Average Price", "min":"Minimum Price"}, 
hover_name="cat_level2", 
hover_data={"cat_level2":False, "max":":$.2f", "mean":":$.2f", "min":":$.2f"}
)

fig.show()
```

If I change the $ symbols to pound symbols (£) this shows customdata in the chart tooltip. According to them they are using the d3 library for currency formatting which claims to use the system locale. I have checked that i am using the correct locale, (which is en_GB.utf-8), so i don't know what else to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added pound signs as hover data for population based on examples from [the official website](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#modifying-the-hovertemplate-of-a-plotly-express-figure).

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
fig = px.bar(df, y='pop', x='country') 
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='pop: \u00A3%{y}')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: it works also with HTML Entity `&#163;` but not `&pound;` - `hovertemplate='pop: &#163;%{y}'`. The same with problem with `&euro;`, `&yen;`, etc. But works with popular `&gt;` (`>`) and `&amp;` (`&`). [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: @furas Dash is a web, so HTML entities are also valid. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful - i am now just trying to get my customdata into the hover template too, can this be done without using graph objects? (instead of using %{x} , %{customdata[0]:.2f} for example?

Comment: i got it to work using customdata like this: fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='<b>%{x}</b><br>Product Count: %{y}<br>Maximum Price: \u00A3%{customdata[0]:.2f}<br>Average Price: \u00A3%{customdata[1]:.2f}<br>Minimum Price: \u00A3%{customdata[2]:.2f}')